# How to append a HTML template using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I have an ajax call which returns me a 2D array as such:

```
[
    {
    "sweetness": "medium",
    "calories": 2359,
    "bitterness": 52
    },

    {
    "sweetness": "low",
    "calories": 4520,
    "bitterness": 34
    },

    {
    "sweetness": "extreme",
    "calories": 3414,
    "bitterness": 12
    }

]
```

My initial HTML template looks like this:

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

I want the end data HTML to look like this:

```
<div id="results">
    <div class="fruit-item">
        <div id="f-calories">medium</div>
        <div id="f-sweetness">2359</div>
        <div id="f- bitterness">52</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fruit-item">
        <div id="f-calories">low</div>
        <div id="f-sweetness">4520</div>
        <div id="f- bitterness">34</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fruit-item">
        <div id="f-calories">extreme</div>
        <div id="f-sweetness">3414</div>
        <div id="f- bitterness">12</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried with a loop like this, but it doesn't work:

```
data.forEach( function( key, value) {
    $(".fruit-item").append("<div id='f-sweetness' > "+key.sweetness+"</div>" );
    $(".fruit-item").append("<div id='f-calories' > "+key.calories+"</div>" );
    $(".fruit-item").append("<div id='f-bitterness' > "+key.bitterness+"</div>" );
});
```

Comment: OT: remember that in a document, `id` 's should never have duplicate values

Comment: @balexandre Oh, I didn't know that. So how do I make it so I can get a similar HTML template out (I'm not restricted by the HTML template. I can change the id/classes).

Comment: Can you show us what the current output is (if its anything at all)? Is it producing nothing, or is it producing fruit-item divs with the wrong content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in HTML,. you shouldn't have duplicate id's... plus, you should actually look into the definition of the function you want to work with if you're new to javascript, for example, `forEach` callback does not have `value` and `key` but rather `currentValue` and `index` as specified in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

a simple way to write what you need is

```
<script>
   var data = [{
        "sweetness": "medium",
        "calories": 2359,
        "bitterness": 52
      }, {
        "sweetness": "low",
        "calories": 4520,
        "bitterness": 34
      }, {
        "sweetness": "extreme",
        "calories": 3414,
        "bitterness": 12
      }];

  $(() => {
      data.forEach((item, idx) => {
          $("#results").append(`
            <div class="fruit-item" data-item="${idx}">
                <div class="f-calories">${item.sweetness}</div>
                <div class="f-sweetness">${item.calories}</div>
                <div class="f-bitterness">${item.bitterness}</div>
            </div>
          `);
      })
  });
</script>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: There might be a mistake? why is idx always 0?

Comment: in a `forEach` the callback has 1 parameters and 2 more, optional, the 2nd parameter is the index... you can simply test in a browser by opening the console and write the javascript there if you're not sure... [here's a live example](https://jsbin.com/cuxacem/edit?css,js,output) if you need it

Answer (score 1):

First of all your HTML is wrong. An id is an identifier that means it has to be unique. Use class instead.

Second thing is that you would append this items to any item. You most probably want to append it to the end of the list so you should use `$('#results').append('')`.

A nice solution with ES6 would be like (it is similar in plain JavaScript):

```
$.each(data, function( key, object) {
    $('#results').append(`
        <div class="fruit-item">
            <div class="f-calories">${object.sweetness}</div>
            <div class="f-sweetness">${object.calories}</div>
            <div class="f-bitterness">${object.bitterness}</div>
        </div>`);
 });
```

Alternativley you might use some easy library like Handlebars (https://handlebarsjs.com/). This way you can add fully compiled HTML templates in a good way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Template Literals inside the *append* method:

```js
data.forEach(i => {
  $("#results").append(`
    <div class="fruit-item">
      <div id="f-calories">${i.calories}</div>
      <div id="f-sweetness">${i.sweetness}</div>
      <div id="f- bitterness">${i.bitterness}</div>
    </div>
  `)
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Wrap data in a $() so it become a jQuery object, then you can use its forEach method.

```
$(data).forEach( function( key, value) {
    $(".fruit-item").append("<div id='f-sweetness' > "+key.sweetness+"</div>" );
    $(".fruit-item").append("<div id='f-calories' > "+key.calories+"</div>" );
    $(".fruit-item").append("<div id='f-bitterness' > "+key.bitterness+"</div>" );
});
```

Comment: Sure. By the way, It would be easier to use JSONparse: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: I think you are confusing jQuery's `.each()` method with native JavaScript's `forEach` method for arrays.